# How to sort SQL query alphabetically but ignoring leading numbers?

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, sorting

I am unable to find the right query for my problem. I have a table in the db and I need to sort it in a very specific manner - the column I am sorting is an address, and it starts with the number, but I need to sort it ignoring the number.

Here is my data set:

```
id  | address
1   | 23 Bridge road
2   | 14 Kennington street
3   | 7  Bridge road
4   | 12 Oxford street
5   | 9  Bridge road
```

I need to sort this like:

```
id | address
1  |  7 Bridge road
2  |  9 Bridge road 
3  | 23 Bridge road
4  | 14 Kennington street
5  | 12 Oxford street
```

So far I got only this:

```
SELECT id, address
FROM propertySearch
Order by address ASC.
```

Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: What RDBMS are you working with?

Comment: Take a look here at using the the `TRIM` function that SQL has http://www.w3resource.com/sql/character-functions/trim.php but tag the database that you're using as there may be better methods, depending on the database

Comment: How are the address stored? Normally you'd store the number and road name in different columns but if not I'd look linto substring and trim to split out the string and remove everything before the first space.

Comment: I suppose you could use regexp-replace or other similar product specific function. But you have still not told us which dbms you're using.

Comment: ahh sorry. i use ms sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this will always be that format(leading number, a space and then the address) , then you can do this:

SQL-Server:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(t.address,CHARINDEX(' ',t.address,1),99)
```

MySQL :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.address,' ',-1)
```

If the format is not constant , you can use SQL-Server `patindex()` :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(t.address,PATINDEX('%[A-z]%',t.address),99)
```

**NOTE:** This is bad DB design!! Each value should be properly stored in its own column, E.G `STREET` , `CITY` , `APARTMANT_NUMBER` ETC, becuase if not, they are leading to exactly this.

Comment: Let's be honest: it will not always be that format.

Comment: Lets be honest, why wouldn't it?

Comment: Some addresses don't have a number. One example: Her Majesty The Queen, Buckingham Palace, London SW1A 1AA

Comment: Then  `PATINDEX` will return 0, and the substring will start from the beggining.

Comment: No, your answer would sort it under 'P' instead of 'B'. You also have problems with typos like "14Kennington street"

Comment: Yea, my bad about the `CHARINDEX` , but `PATINDEX` will deal with the first problem fine.

Comment: What if the address 119a Latimer street? query works fine if the first characters are all number but if the address is 119a Latimer street, it needs to be groupped with L rather than a. How can i do that?

Comment: It should be clear by now that you need to normalize that table, i.e. move the number to its own column.

Answer (score 2):

If you use SQL Server, you can use a combination of `PATINDEX` and `STUFF`:

```
SELECT *, STUFF(T.address, 1, PATINDEX('%[A-z]%', T.address) - 1, '')
FROM #Table1 AS T
ORDER BY STUFF(T.address, 1, PATINDEX('%[A-z]%', T.address) - 1, '')
```

`PATINDEX` will find first letter index in your string and `STUFF` is used to trim everything from the beginning to that index.

That's output:

```
id  address                 No column name)
---------------------------------------------
1   23 Bridge road          Bridge road
3   7  Bridge road          Bridge road
5   9  Bridge road          Bridge road
2   14 Kennington street    Kennington street
4   12 Oxford street        Oxford street
```

I also noticed you have different order in your expected output. If that was intented. You need to use ROW_NUMBER:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY STUFF(T.address, 1, PATINDEX('%[A-z]%', T.address) - 1, ''), T.id) AS ID, T.address
FROM #Table1 AS T;
```

This query will generate new ID for each row.
Result:

```
id  address
------------------------
1   23 Bridge road
2   7  Bridge road
3   9  Bridge road
4   14 Kennington street
5   12 Oxford street
```

---

Anyway, this is rather hacky solution.

I'd suggest you to store your address in seperate columns, such as street name, postal code, house number, house letter (optional), town, etc. This will be a much better approach.

Comment: maybe a problem if the address is like this `25a Bridge Road`

Comment: That's actually correct. Gotta find a way to fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this kind of operations is more for business layer.
If you load all data to the .net code - sorting will be more easy, more readable and maintainable.

```vb
Public Class Address

    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property AddressData As String

    'This property can be used for sorting       
    Public ReadOnly Property SortedKey As String
        Get
           Dim rawData As IEnumerable(Of String) = Me.AddressData.Split(" "c).Skip(1)
           Return String.Join(" ", rawData)
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Then use it with LINQ

```vb
Dim loaded As List(Of Address) = yourLoadFunction()
Dim sorted = loaded.OrderBy(Function(item) item.SortedKey).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've tagged vb.net, guess you use MS SQL. If you are always separating street number and street name with a blank space, try ordering like this:

`ORDER BY RIGHT([address], LEN([address]) - CHARINDEX(' ', [address], 1))`

Comment: It will fail if there are two number sequences split by space. i.e. `7 5 Bridge Road`.

Comment: Sure it will, but in a normal situation street number should not have a number with a blank space.

Comment: You never know what users might input.

Comment: yeap. data better be validated when inputting.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @Table table (id int,address varchar(100))
Insert into @Table values
(1,'23 Bridge road'),
(2,'14 Kennington street'),
(3,'7 Bridge road'),
(4,'12 Oxford street'),
(5,'9 Bridge road')

Select * From @Table
 Order By substring(address,patindex('%[a-z]%',address),200)
         ,cast(substring(address,1,charindex(' ',address)) as int)
```

Returns

```
id  address
3   7 Bridge road
5   9 Bridge road
1   23 Bridge road
2   14 Kennington street
4   12 Oxford street
```

Comment: But sorting Oxford street before Kennington street is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: @Twinkles Thanks, I was missing the trailing %.  Great catch.